# Converting (x,y,z) coord to single index that minimizes "distance" of elements to neighbors

Tags: coordinate-transformation

If you have a fixed-size (N) 3D space, with integral coordinates in [0,N[ , how can you convert those (x,y,z) coordinates to a single linear index [0,N*N*N[ , where the average distance of one coordinate (x,y,z) to it's next neighbors (x-1,y,z), (x+1,y,z), ... (26 neighbors) is minimized, compared to the simplistic "index = x + N*y + N*N*z" formula?

An expensive formula is an acceptable solution in my case because N is fixed and not too big, so I can compute the mapping a single time and cache the result, if it is expensive.

The reason I need this is that I'm trying to compress same-values based on proximity, and so putting neighbor values next to each other in the array improves the compression rate.

If you can point to some Java code it would be even better ...